# Read XML in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to read the value of node `<IdChk>` with the following code:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML
    SET @XML ='
<ListChk >
      <IdChk>26</IdChk>
      <IdChk>29</IdChk>
      <IdChk>35</IdChk>
  <obs>test</obs>
  <Fol>10944</Fol>
</ListChk>'

SELECT Y.V.value('IdChk[1]','int') AS chk   
FROM @XML.nodes('/ListChk') X(V)
CROSS APPLY X.V.nodes('IdChk') Y(V)
```

but the value this query return is null

[image]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are actually using something on the root element you can shorten your query like this...

```
SELECT Y.V.value('.','int') AS chk   
FROM @XML.nodes('/ListChk/IdChk') Y(V)
```

... (even then you could use xpath to navigate to parent nodes with `.value`

```
SELECT 
    Y.V.value('.','int') AS chk 
    ,Y.V.value('../obs[1]','varchar(4)') AS obs
    ,Y.V.value('../Fol[1]','int') AS Fol
FROM @XML.nodes('/ListChk/IdChk') Y(V)

chk obs     Fol
26  test    10944
29  test    10944
35  test    10944
```

Answer (score 2):

Your XQuery *already* selects the `<IdChk>` nodes - you don't need to (and must not) use the `.value('IdChk[1]', 'int')` to try and grab the value.

Instead, you need to just read out the value of those nodes like this:

```
SELECT 
    Y.V.value('.', 'int') AS chk   
FROM 
    @XML.nodes('/ListChk') X(V)
CROSS APPLY 
    X.V.nodes('IdChk') Y(V)
```

Comment: thank you for taking a moment to answer my question!